# How to make a cellphone tripod?

Tags: substitute-tool, phone, photography

I want to take a photo of myself. Ideally, I should use a tripod, but I don't have one and do not want to buy one.

What can I use instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how expensive you think they are, but I got a generic cellphone tripod off ebay for just a few bucks.

Answer (score 10):

In a pinch you can use socks and a rubber band:

Get four pairs of socks that have been "folded" the way you fold socks. (I'm pretty sure everybody folds socks the same way, but just in case, I'm talking about folding them [like this](http://www.wikihow.com/Fold-Socks).) Arrange the pairs of socks in a 2x2 square, aligned like cans of beer in a 6-pack. Then pull a rubber band around them so that they're pulled snugly together.

Stick your phone in the middle of this so that it bisects the sock quartet. If you push it in deep enough, the phone will be held in place by the pressure of the rubber band. You'll want to adjust the orientations of the socks and the rubber band so that the phone is aligned the right way (and there's no sock blocking the camera).

If you use hefty socks, the resulting setup is fairly sturdy and surprisingly adjustable. The problem is that the camera is only lifted a few inches above whatever surface you place the socks on. If you're taking a photo at your desk, you may have to stack a few books on it, and place the sock-tripod on top of those.

Comment: Nice answer Ryan, and welcome to Lifehacks! Excellent answer, +1. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site :D

Answer (score 1):

The bottle tripod won´t work for a cell phone, but it inspired me. Haven´t tried it, so no guarantee there, but it might work:

- Take two pairs of pliers (with rubber applied to the handles, if you have) or two clothspins.
- Clamp each of them into a bottle and put the bottles side by side.
- Use a table, chair, stool, footstool, cardboard box or a combination to get to the desired level.
- Set the timer on your camera app, put the phone between the handles and off you go.

You may have to practice a bit until you get the angle right. A sock or a handkerchief might help.

Comment: P.S.: instead of using the timer, you may want to consider buying a BlueTooth Selfie Trigger. There are even boom boxes that have one built in.

Answer (score -1):

Most modern cameras follow a standard for attaching to tripods, the post is 1/4 inch in diameter with a coarse thread. Any hardware store will have bolts of varying length that fit this.
The question then becomes "What do you want to stick this post through?" You can make a base from anything you're willing to drill through: a board, a chair, cigar store indian, or a [clamp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DD6XG); or make a [bottle tripod](http://www.diyphotography.net/the-super-small-bottle-cap-tripod).

Comment: It's a cell phone, not a standalone camera.